# Testing Redux with testing library getting this error: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid : but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to test my React Native App redux store using Testing library, I followed the Redux documentation to create a Wrapper provider in order to pass the store to the component to test, in this case my LoginScreen component. But I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `LoginScreen`.
    at LoginScreen (/Users/macbookpro/Proyectos/Personales/antifappi/src/screens/notauthenticated/LoginScreen.tsx:41:22)
    at Provider (/Users/macbookpro/Proyectos/Personales/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:19:3)
    at Wrapper (/Users/macbookpro/Proyectos/Personales/app/src/utils/test-utils.tsx:29:22)
```

This is my "**test-utils.tsx**" that I copy from redux documentation:

```
export const renderWithProviders = (
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
) => {

  const Wrapper = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element => {

    return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
              { children }
            </Provider>
    )
  }

  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) 
  
}
```

and this is my test for loginscreen:

```
describe("Login Screen", () => {
    describe("layout", () => {
        it("render correctly", async () => {

            component = renderWithProviders(<LoginScreen />, { preloadedState: {
                auth: {
                    status: 'checking',
                    loadingAuth: false,
                    user: null,
                    message: '',
                    token: null,
                    goSettingUp: false,
                }
            }, store: store});
            console.log(component);

            expect(component).toBeDefined();
});
});
});
```

I hope some can come across with some advice to solve this issues that I have days trying to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Far too much code. Please read [mre] and then [edit] to reduce what you've posted to the absolute minimum lines of code needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KenWhite I made an edit in my question. I suspect that the problem come from the renderWithProviders because if I try to render directly from testing library render method it render, but with the error that it needs a provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was mocking reanimated twice, I just deleted one of them and now is working fine. So be careful of what and how you are mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have write the following in your test file

```
jest.mock('react-redux', ...
```

Just remove that part, or if you want to mock some of the redux properties, use the following code example (typesript)

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
   const originalModule = jest.requireActual<typeof import('react-redux')>('react-redux');

   return {
      ...originalModule,
      // you code here
   };
});
```